# Multiprocessing in Python 3.4 does not work with imported module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing in Python 3.4.3 to speed up my code. I have a problem with getting back my results. I have tried the following simple code, which works just fine.

```
    import numpy
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from functools import partial
    from OpenDutchWordnet import Wn_grid_parser, le, les, synset, relation

    def funct(arg1, value):
        return arg1 * value

    if __name__ == '__main__':

         #------FOR TESTING-------
         t=[1,2,3,4]
         arg1=4
         pool=Pool(processes=1)
         func=partial(funct,  arg1)
         print("func: ", func)
         m4=pool.map(func,t)
         print(m4)
         #------/FOR TESTING-------
```

Of course, I would like to run more than 1 processes. And the code which I would like to run is the following,

```
    import numpy
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from functools import partial
    from OpenDutchWordnet import Wn_grid_parser, le, les, synset, relation

    def funct2(arg1, value):
        return arg1.get_relations(value)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        myparser= Wn_grid_parser(Wn_grid_parser.odwn)
        l_sensesofwoord = myparser.lemma_get_generator("man")
        sense=l_sensesofwoord[0]
        synsetid_sense=sense.get_synset_id()
        t=["has_hyperonym", "has_holonym"]
        arg1=myparser.synsets_find_synset(synsetid_sense)

        f=partial(funct2, arg1)
        print("f is: ", f)
        m1=pool.map(f,t)
```

When running this code, I get the following errormessage.

```
f is:  functools.partial(<function funct2 at 0x00000000046D5378>, <synset.Synset object at 0x000000005011DDA0>) 

multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
  result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
  return list(map(*args))
File "C:\Users\UTRSB\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\mycode\multi.py", line 14, in funct2
  return numpy.asarray(arg1.get_relations(value))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenDutchWordnet\synset.py", line 98, in get_relations
  for relation_el in self.synset_el.iterfind(xml_query)]
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenDutchWordnet\synset.py", line 97, in <listcomp>
  return [Relation(relation_el)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 156, in select
  for elem in result:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 88, in select
  for elem in result:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 89, in select
  for e in elem.iterchildren(tag):
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1363, in lxml.etree._Element.iterchildren (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:50501)
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2730, in lxml.etree.ElementChildIterator.__cinit__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:66739)
File "apihelpers.pxi", line 24, in lxml.etree._assertValidNode (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:14133)
AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at 53353160
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/UTRSB/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/mycode/multi.py", line 52, in <module>
  m1=pool.map(f,t)
File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
  return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
  raise self._value
AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at 53353160
```

I have also tried using another way:    `result=pool.apply_async(geefAlleGloss,[p])`
this works just fine, but when I want to use get() to obtain the results. I end up with the same error.     `answer=result.get()`

I think the error is somewhere in the map function. At first, I thought it had something to to with the imported modules from OpenDutchWordnet that I use. But as the partial function works, the error should be caused by the get() and/or map() function.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think the error is in your parser code, not related to multi processing. Try to run the main parsing without multi processing and see if it works fine.

Comment: @masnun thanks for your comment. It works fine if I run the main parsing without multiprocessing. The error occurs after the statement print("f is: ", f). So I  think that there must be a reason why the map function does not work with imported modules as the ones from OpenDutchWordnet.

Comment: multi processing won't work with items that are not pickle-able.

Comment: @masnun True, funct2 returns a list of relation objects. As I have imported the class "relation", it should be pickleable according to the  documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).